# How to setup custom header fields for emscripten Fetch API from c++

Tags: c++, emscripten, fetch-api

C++ request looks like this

```cpp
emscripten_fetch_attr_t attr;
emscripten_fetch_attr_init(&attr);
strcpy(attr.requestMethod, "GET");

// case 1       
// static std::vector<const char*> custom_headers = {"Token", "00000000", nullptr};
// attr.requestHeaders = custom_headers.data();

// case 2
static const char* custom_headers[3] = {"Token", "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", nullptr};
attr.requestHeaders = custom_headers;

attr.attributes = EMSCRIPTEN_FETCH_LOAD_TO_MEMORY;
attr.onsuccess = onDownload;
attr.onerror = onError;
emscripten_fetch(&attr, "http://localhost:9080/api/session");
```

XHR works fine except header fields - they are not set in both cases. 
Doc comment from `emscripten_fetch_attr_t` struct say:

```cpp
// Points to an array of strings to pass custom headers to the request. This array takes the form
// {"key1", "value1", "key2", "value2", "key3", "value3", ..., 0 }; Note especially that the array
// needs to be terminated with a null pointer.
const char * const *requestHeaders;
```

[Emscripten FetchAPI reference](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/api_reference/fetch.html) and [code tests](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/tree/master/tests) has no example of `requestHeaders` usage.

How exactly I can set my own request header fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason why it didn't assigned any custom headers is really stupid - it has no valid and tested implementation in current version yet:

emscripten/**1.37.13**/system/lib/fetch/emscripten_fetch.cpp : Line 78

```
fetch->__attributes.requestHeaders = 0;// TODO:strdup(fetch->__attributes.requestHeaders);
```

As temporary solution it's enough to simply assign it to itself

```
fetch->__attributes.requestHeaders = fetch->__attributes.requestHeaders
```

And then you'll be able to use second case from my question:

```
static const char* custom_headers[3] = {"Token", "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", nullptr};
attr.requestHeaders = custom_headers;
```

Comment: this makes no sense. if `fetch->__attributes.requestHeaders` is null, assigning it to itself is going to overwrite null by null.

Comment: but yes, `fetch->__attributes.requestHeaders` is null. I tried to do this instead: `fetch->__attributes.requestHeaders = custom_headers`, but it is still not working for me. the headers are not going through.

Comment: @mchiasson the line above looks like `fetch->__attributes.password = fetch->__attributes.password ? strdup(fetch->__attributes.password) : 0; // TODO: free`. You probably should do the same check except you need custom `strdup`, because headers are null-terminated strings of key and value and end of all headers should be also `\0`.